# Unable to see the response.data in console while logging

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I am using a Post method service in a form, while submitting it I should be able to see the response.data in the console as I have console logged it, but I am unable to see it. I also tried with console.log(response) or console.log(data) but none of them is working. Below is the code snippet where I am having the issue:

```js
const onSubmithandler = async (data) => {
  await axios
    .post("http://localhost:5000..", data)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      reset();
      setMessage("User registered successfully");
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

While submitting the data in the form should I be able to see the response.data thing in the console? I tried, but it isn't visible.

Comment: `http://localhost:5000..` does not look like a valid URL. Also, do you see the error message?

Comment: there is an easier way to inspect network calls. simply open the devtools and switch to the network tab, from there you will see all network calls and you can inspect there responses.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing the console log because your page is reloading on submit, add e.preventDefault() to the top of your function.

```
const onSubmithandler = async (event, data) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  await axios
    .post("http://localhost:5000..", data)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      reset();
      setMessage("User registered successfully");
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

Comment: Can you tell me where should I place the preventDefault() in the above code snippet that I have provided?

Comment: @AnkanChanda sure, updated original answer

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. I tried but it is coming to this error:
 event.preventDefault is not a function
    at onSubmithandler (Userfor

Comment: @AnkanChanda Please, show how and where you call the function